# BASH_ENV being ignored in AWS Ubuntu 20.04 crontab

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron, aws

With both

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=/home/ubuntu/.bashrc
```

set on AWS Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS crontab, `.bashrc` isn't sourced. I ran into this with the error `/bin/bash: python: command not found`. `python` is only available within an environment whose command is made available in `.bashrc`. In my cronjob, I activate the environment and then I call `python`. (As I debugged, I realized the environment wasn't being activated, either, confirming the fact that `.bashrc` wasn't being read.)

I've made sure with `ps -p $$` that `SHELL=/bin/bash` is actually running `bash` instead of what would be `sh` (given that `BASH_ENV` is not effective in `sh`). I also made sure that the `BASH_ENV` variable is properly set by running `echo $BASH_ENV` in one of the cronjobs. It's just not being sourced.

I've run these exact same cronjobs in crontab an another, non-AWS machine and they worked fine. I've already reviewed many related questions ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67940/cron-ignores-variables-defined-in-bashrc-and-bash-profile), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138577/how-to-guarantee-availability-of-bash-env/138609#138609), [4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130941/bash-env-and-cron-jobs?rq=1)), but everything that I've done seems according to expectations.

Another thing I tried in the AWS machine is to invert the order of `SHELL` and `BASH_ENV` with no results:

```
BASH_ENV=/home/ubuntu/.bashrc
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

I know I can source `.bashrc` before every cronjob. I'd rather set it up once to avoid mistakes due to individual-cronjob editing in the future and because I'd rather edit one single line than however many cronjobs in the future if I have to set this up in another machine as well. At the same time, I did try prepending `source ~/.bashrc`, `source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc`, `. ~/.bashrc` and `. /home/ubuntu/.bashrc` and they didn't have the desired effect.

Comment: I suggest you debug it by adding a `xargs -0 echo </proc/$$/cmdline; realpath /proc/$$/exe; set` command to your crontab, and checking its output. Keep in mind that bash will ignore `BASH_ENV` when it's called as `sh` (i.e. its first argument is `sh` or `-sh`)

Answer (score 2):

Figured out that the AWS `~/.bashrc` file has the following code at the start, which doesn't run the rest of `~/.bashrc` script if the shell is not interactive (and cronjobs use non-interactive shells):

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
   *i*) ;;
     *) return;;
esac
```

Should've read the whole preexisting AWS `~/.bashrc` file before using it. As Uncle Billy mentioned in the comments, some distributions have this

> in order to avoid loading all the interactive stuff (completion, functions, aliases) when the `.bashrc` is sourced when bash is executed to run a non-interactive command via ssh.

Given my previous experiences, it made the usual (maybe not best) practice of just appending commands to `~/.bashrc` confusing.

It's unclear to me if the rest of the file may have adverse effects for non-interactive shells, but I don't think it would add too much overhead. This is the original content of the ~/.bashrc file:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: That's not only an AWS thing. The `.bashrc` of most distros is like that, in order to avoid loading all the interactive stuff (completion, functions, aliases) when the `.bashrc` is sourced when bash is executed to run a non-interactive command via ssh.

Comment: @UncleBilly makes sense. what's the best practice in these cases for commands you need executed in non-interactive shells?