# If processes inherit the parent's environment, why do we need export?

Tags: shell, process, environment-variables

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export) that the purpose of `export` in a shell is to make the variable available to sub-processes started from the shell.

However, I have also read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17758/exception-of-inheritance-of-environment-variables?rq=1) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127284/4531) that *"Processes inherit their environment from their parent (the process which started them)."*

If this is the case, why do we need `export`? What am  I missing?

Are shell variables not part of the environment by default? What is the difference?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Your assumption is that shell variables are *in the environment*. This is incorrect. The `export` command is what defines a name to be in the environment at all. Thus:

```
a=1 b=2
export b
```

results in the current *shell* knowing that `$a` expands to 1 and `$b` to 2, but subprocesses will not know anything about `a` because it is not part of the environment (even in the current shell).

Some useful tools:

- `set`: Useful for viewing the current shell's parameters, exported-or-not
- `set -k`: Sets *assigned args* in the environment. Consider `f() { set -k; env; }; f a=1`
- `set -a`: Tells the shell to put any name that gets set into the environment. Like putting `export` before every assignment. Useful for `.env` files, as in `set -a; . .env; set +a`.
- `export`: Tells the shell to put a name in the environment. Export and assignment are two entirely different operations.
- `env`: As an external command, `env` can only tell you about the *inherited* environment, thus, it's useful for sanity checking.
- `env -i`: Useful for clearing the environment before starting a subprocess.

Alternatives to `export`:

1. `name=val command` # Assignment before command exports that name to the command.
2. `declare/local -x name` # Exports name, particularly useful in shell functions when you want to avoid exposing the name to outside scope.
3. `set -a` # Exports every following assignment.

### Motivation

So why do shells need to have their own variables and environment that is different? I'm sure there are some historical reasons, but I think the main reason is scoping. The environment is for subprocesses, but there are lots of operations you can do in the shell without forking a subprocess. Suppose you loop:

```
for i in {0..50}; do
    somecommand
done
```

Why waste memory for `somecommand` by including `i`, making its environment any bigger than it needs to be? What if the variable name you chose in the shell just happens to mean something unintended to the program? (Personal favorites of mine include `DEBUG` and `VERBOSE`. Those names are used everywhere and rarely namespaces adequately.)

### What is the environment if not the shell?

Sometimes to understand Unix behavior you have to look at the syscalls, the basic API for interacting with the kernel and OS. Here, we're looking at the `exec` family of calls, which is what the shell uses when it creates a subprocess. Here's a quote from the [manpage for `exec(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) (emphasis mine):

> The `execle()` and `execvpe()` functions allow the caller to specify the environment of the executed program via the argument envp. The envp argument is an array of pointers to null-terminated strings and must be terminated by a NULL pointer. **The other functions take the environment for the new process image from the external variable environ in the calling process.**

So writing `export somename` in the shell would be equivalent to copying the name to the global dictionary `environ` in C. But assigning `somename` without exporting it would be just like assigning it in C, without copying it to the `environ` variable.

Comment: `set -k` is so that one can use `cmd ENVVAR=value` in place of `ENVVAR=value cmd`, that won't work in your example unless `set -k` was run prior to invoking `f`. Also, not many shells support it nowadays and only for backward compatibility with the Bourne shell. In the Bourne (or Korn) shell, that wouldn't work for functions. And because it affects shell parsing, it has to be in effect at the time the shell _reads_ the code that makes use of it there.

Comment: You may also want to mention `set -a`

Comment: This is a helpful answer but I feel like it should also address how/why shell variables are different than environment variables, 'cuz that's super confusing.

Comment: @mblakesley ok, edited. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @kojiro wow, thanks for the effort! But no, I just wanted something more basic that elaborates on the first few sentences. After re-reading, I think my biggest question is still: "what's the environment if not the shell?" Obviously this can be found elsewhere, but it's helpful context here.

Comment: @mblakesley OK, I tried again.

Comment: @kojiro Great answer. One suggestion on the wording though - "copying the name to the **global** dictionary", might cause confusion. Each process has its own environment right? So global makes it sound like there is a universal dictionary for all processes, which I think is false?

Comment: @Ambareesh my comment was referring to the `exec` manpage, which calls the variable _external_. An [extern is a global](https://www.gnu.org/software/c-intro-and-ref/manual/html_node/Extern-Declarations.html). Anyway, the environment that subprocesses get is a copy of the parent process's, so if the child changes a value it doesn't affect the parent or siblings.

Answer (score 34):

There's a difference between shell variables and environment variables.  If you define a shell variable without `export`ing it, it is not added to the processes environment and thus not inherited to its children.

Using `export` you tell the shell to add the shell variable to the environment.  You can test this using `printenv` (which just prints its environment to `stdout`, since it's a child-process you see the effect of `export`ing variables):

```
#!/bin/sh

MYVAR="my cool variable"

echo "Without export:"
printenv | grep MYVAR

echo "With export:"
export MYVAR
printenv | grep MYVAR
```

Answer (score 6):

A variable, once exported, is part of the environment. `PATH` is exported in the shell itself, while custom variables can be exported as needed. Using some setup code:

```
$ cat subshell.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare | grep -e '^PATH=' -e '^foo='
```

Compare

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH=/bin
export foo=bar
declare | grep -e '^PATH=' -e '^foo='
./subshell.sh
$ ./test.sh 
PATH=/bin
foo=bar
PATH=/bin
foo=bar
```

With

```
$ cat test2.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PATH=/bin
foo=bar
declare | grep -e '^PATH=' -e '^foo='
./subshell.sh
$ ./test2.sh 
PATH=/bin
foo=bar
PATH=/bin
```

Since `foo` is not exported by the shell, and `test2.sh` never exported it, it was not part of the environment of `subshell.sh` in the last run.

Answer (score 3):

It's not about the parent / child relationship.

When a process forks a child, the child is an almost exact copy of the parent, so it inherits everything.

In:

```
$ var=1; (echo "$var"; var=2); echo "$var"
1
1
```

Where most shells implement the `(...)` subshell environment by forking a child process, that child process has access to the same data as the parent.

The environment variables are about preserving data (in that case `key=value` strings) across *execution* of a new command within a same process.

When you do:

```
$ export VAR=value
$ printenv VAR
value
```

The shell forks a child process  (which inherits everything), but then in that child process executes the `printenv` command (and with `exec printenv VAR`, the forking is skipped).

It's only at that point that the memory of that child process is completely wiped before loading the new executable, so everything is lost. The environment variables are passed in the third argument of the `execve("/usr/bin/printenv", ["printenv", "VAR"], environ)` system call.

The shell places the `VAR=value` inside that `environ` array of strings for `printenv` to retrieve it, and in Bourne-like  shells, only the variables that have been marked with the `export` attributes are put there (with some variation in behaviour when those variables are not scalar variables).

Some shells like `rc` and derivatives put all their variables in the environment even the array ones (which they need to encode some specific way which is only understood by other instances of themselves).

The Bourne shell had env vars even more separated from shell vars in that shell variables were created from env var on startup, but you had to export those shell variables even if they were initially imported from the environment for  any modification made to them to be propagated to executed commands. It's similar in the C-shell, where you have to use `setenv` instead of `set` to set values of variables if you want the modification to be exported to executed commands.

`ksh` also exports the *attributes* of exported variable via the special `A__z` env var. `bash` can also export its *options* to other executed `bash` instances via the `SHELLOPTS` and `BASHOPTS` environment variables.

In `perl`, the environment variables are mapped to the `%ENV` associative array variable.

Note that env var names can contain any sequence of bytes other than `=` and NUL, and the third argument of `execve()` can contain more than one definition for a same variable and even strings that don't contain `=` characters, while shells have much greater restrictions as to what their variable names may contain. You'll find some variation in behaviour as to what shells do with environment strings that can't be mapped to shell variables.

Answer (score 3):

In summary:

- processes DO inherit environment variables from their parents
- in bash, $a=1 creates a 'normal' variable, not an environment variable
- export a=1 creates an environment variable for the process of the terminal (there are also other ways to do it)
- there are other ways to pass environment data to a child process

Comment: in Bash or any other POSIXy shell, `$a=1` doesn't create any variables, `a=1` does. Also, "for the process of the terminal" sounds, well, confusing? I guess you mean "the process running at the foreground at the time on that terminal", but even then, that's a shell command, you can't just give to any process. Then, I also wonder if this answer really adds anything to the four earlier ones.

Comment: I thought that the variable is created (most likely added to a dictionary) in the process executing the command, which, I figured would be the process running the terminal.
What I aimed with this answer is (as the first line states) a summary, a not so deep answer to the question.
Thank you for the critique, I will look into how commands are executed in the terminal.