# Relation between shell start up processes and environment of parent process

Tags: shell, environment-variables, startup, variable

"How are shell variables related to the environment that a process started by the shell has on start-up?"

I read [If processes inherit the parent's environment, why do we need export?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/if-processes-inherit-the-parents-environment-why-do-we-need-export)

My current possibly wrong understanding is that shell variables aren't in the environment. Variables must be exported to the environment so a child can inherit them from a parent, but I don't see where start-up comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

Your current understanding of "variables must be exported to the environment so a child can inherit them from a parent" seems correct to me.

Processes other than a shell have environment variables, the C language interface for this is `getenv()` and `setenv()`, from `stdlib.h`. Unix, Linux and *BSD operating system shells just happen to make environment variables look like ordinary, non-inherited shell variables.

So I guess that the answer to your specific question is: only shell variables that are exported to the shell's environment show up in a child process' environment.