# Why my newly created user is not inheriting $PATH variable

Tags: environment-variables, docker, non-root-user, useradd, alpine-linux

I added a new user `dev` on my Alpine based image. After switching to the new user I see env variables are different in case of both `root` and `dev` user. Specially `$PATH` variable is different. But I think it should not be different as it is **exported** globally on `/etc/profile`.

```
$ cat /etc/profile

export CHARSET=UTF-8
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
export PAGER=less
export PS1='\h:\w\$ '
umask 022

for script in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
        if [ -r $script ] ; then
                . $script
        fi
done
composer(){ su-exec deploy composer.phar "$@"; }
```

`$PATH` variable in case of root user

```
# env | grep $PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

`$PATH` variable in case of `dev`

```
# adduser -D -u 2500 -s /bin/sh dev
# su dev
$ env | grep $PATH
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
```

I know I can add `.sh` inside `profile.d` dir and export the `$PATH` variable again, but why it is not inheriting as per  this 
question ([If processes inherit the parent's environment, why do we need export?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130985))?  Is there any other way I can inherit the env variables except creating a new profile for `dev` user ? Where those env variables has been set for `dev` user?

Comment: Are you asking why it is not inheriting, or why it is not getting set? (You may be using some technical words incorrectly) Please show process, so that we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure what `/bin/sh` is on Alpine but, traditionally, `/etc/profile` is only sourced for *login* shells (i.e. `su --login` or `su -`)

Comment: In addition to what has been said, it's best not to do what you're trying to do via `/etc/profile`. It's much better to create a shell init file in `/etc/profile.d` and make it executable.

Comment: Is there a `~/.profile` for user dev?  Are you using `su - dev` ?